# Weird errors in python, need help to debug

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a bigger script, that tries to calculate some scientific stuff. The code is working (at the beginning) but then after some time stops. The errors differ. Sometime i get `Too many opened files` error, which is very strange, as i hardly open 7-8 files, and i am using `with open` so it must be closed. Sometimes after the 7-8-9th iteration the script just runs out of memory, which is very strange, as at previous turns it hardly uses 5 GB, and the server has 500 GB of memory.

The code is ~500 lines lone ad it look like this:

```
import math
import multiprocessing
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import gc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

from biopy import energy


class InnerCycle:
    def __init__(self, work_dir):
        self.CPU = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
        self.ROSETTA_DIR = '/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/rosetta_src_2016.13.58602_bundle/main'
        self.INPUT_UNBOUND = "/dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/5e0m_no_ligand.pdb"
        self.WORK_DIR = work_dir
        self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES = ['fa_atr', 'fa_rep', 'fa_sol', 'fa_elec', 'hbond_sr_bb', 'hbond_lr_bb', 'hbond_bb_sc', 'hbond_sc', 'rama', 'omega', 'fa_dun', 'p_aa_pp']
        self.PEPTIDE_KD = {
            # SPR meresek
            "RDGSTQTE": 1e-6,
            "EDKATQTL": 2e-6,
            "NTKMTQTP": 2e-6,
            "YNKEVQTV": 3e-6,
            "GDASTQTD": 7e-6,
            "QNKECQTE": 1.35e-6,
            # Chica
            "IDAATQTE": 4e-7,
            "SEVGTQTS": 6.3e-6,
            "ACAGTQTA": 1e-2,
            "RSTTTQTD": 5.2e-6,
            # PAK1
            "RDVATSPI": 4.2e-5,
            # Myosin 5
            # "DDKNTMTD": 8.8e-6
            # Tamas talalt
            "GDKSTQTD": 5.6e-7,
            "VDKSTQTD": 7e-8,
            "GSRGTQTE": 1.64e-6,
            "VSRGTQTE": 8e-8,
            "ICAGTQTD": 1.14e-6,
            "STTGTQCD": 12.8e-6,
            # Random peptides
            "EQKSNDAS": 1e-2,
            "GSAEIRAH": 1e-2,
            "RRQVKDNR": 1e-2,
            "IDTGITVS": 1e-2,
            "MELIWNLC": 1e-2,
            "CLDWMTMP": 1e-2,
            "LRQGLLPV": 1e-2,
            "NEAYPCPC": 1e-2,
            "NADNGTTV": 1e-2,
            "QALSQHVW": 1e-2,
            "VHTGCKDF": 1e-2,
            "PGVAPTLV": 1e-2,
            "PSIPISRQ": 1e-2,
            "PPGPEKVP": 1e-2,
            "KDFINFIS": 1e-2,
            "EILMQQFL": 1e-2,
            "ERAELQAG": 1e-2,
            "LGVASEDE": 1e-2,
            "SSVSTSNA": 1e-2,
            "GMDLDLAS": 1e-2,
            "VSMLSAIR": 1e-2,
            "GTYRCEAT": 1e-2,
            "PQNGGSSD": 1e-2,
            "RKAAVLIF": 1e-2,
            "QSTIPEHI": 1e-2,
            "LGLDKRQS": 1e-2,
            "FWDVVKRQ": 1e-2,
            "NHNQKCKE": 1e-2,
            "RCKFFSLT": 1e-2,
            "ASPRTVTI": 1e-2,
            # SPR 2. round
            "LDKQTQTP": 4e-6,
            "VDKETNTE": 8e-6,
            "VPKQTQTP": 5e-6,
            "YSKETQTP": 8e-6,
            "VDKAVQCS": 7e-6,
            "KDTGVQTD": 1e-5,
            "QHKECQTD": 9e-6,
            "RDQAVQTG": 9e-6
        }
        print("Creating the structures ...")
        # start = time.time()
        for _ in p.imap_unordered(self.main_func, self.PEPTIDE_KD.keys()):
            # print("Time elapsed on {} : {:.2f}min)".format(x, int(time.time() - start) / 60))
            pass
        print("Minimizing the domain...")
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            '{}/source/bin/relax.linuxgccrelease -nstruct 1 -out:file:silent {}/domain_minimized.silent -out:file:silent_struct_type binary -s {} -score:weights {}/weights.wts'.format(
                self.ROSETTA_DIR, self.WORK_DIR, self.INPUT_UNBOUND, self.WORK_DIR), shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = proc.communicate()
        if err:
            sys.exit(err.decode())
        print("Structures are ready!")
        print('Reading energies to calculate the partition functions ...')
        # Reading the energies parallel
        self.COMPLEX_ENERGY = {}
        self.LIGAND_ENERGY = {}
        self.DOMAIN_ENERGY = energy('{}/domain_minimized.silent'.format(self.WORK_DIR))

        for x in p.imap_unordered(self.read_energies, self.PEPTIDE_KD.keys()):
            self.COMPLEX_ENERGY[x[0]] = x[1]
            self.LIGAND_ENERGY[x[0]] = x[2]
        #
        print('Finished reading energies ...')
        print('Minimizing the energy weights ...')
        bound = [(0, None) for _ in self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES]
        start_points = [1 for _ in self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES]
        # start_points = [0.049454984778022501, 1.0811964401313245e-16, 0.019417178401552562, 0.74966259917739431, -9.8627227576030013e-18, 0.7190273821671308, 0.81862557829921956,
        #                 0.82527639772869144, 0.48343139163199061, 0.73645662699706216, 0.4707545503593048, 1.705196654171699]

        res = minimize(self.minimizing_func, np.array(start_points), method='SLSQP', bounds=bound, options={'disp': True})
        print()
        print('Minimization done!')
        print('Final weights:')
        print("--------")
        print(list(res.x))
        print("--------")
        print('PEPTIDE\tPredicted Kd\tExperimantal Kd\tLogDif')
        self.minimizing_func([1 for _ in self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES], prt=True)
        print()
        print('Energy weights:')
        self.ener_dict = {}
        for num, j in enumerate(self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES):
            print(j, '\t{:.4f}'.format(res.x[num]))
            self.ener_dict[j] = res.x[num]

    def get_result(self):
        return self.ener_dict

    def mutate_ligand(self, seq):
        # tm = time.time()
        if os.path.isfile("input.pdb"):
            return
        # print("Mutating the ligand to {} ...".format(seq))
        with open("resfile", "w") as file_name:
            file_name.write("NATRO # default command that applies to everything without a non- default setting; do not repack\nSTART\n")
            for num, j in enumerate(seq):
                file_name.write("{} L PIKAA {} # Change 468 pos in A chain to Alanine\n".format(num + 468, j))
            proc = subprocess.Popen(
                '{}/source/bin/fixbb.linuxgccrelease -s /dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/5e0m_prep.pdb -nstruct 1 -ex1 -ex2 -resfile resfile {}.pdb'.format(self.ROSETTA_DIR, seq,
                                                                                                                                                              seq),
                shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            _, err = proc.communicate()
        if err:
            sys.exit(err)
        os.rename("5e0m_prep_0001.pdb", "input.pdb")
        # print("Mutation of {} done in {:.2f} minutes".format(seq, (time.time() - tm) / 60))
        return

    def prepack(self, seq, overwrite=False):
        # tm = time.time()
        if os.path.isfile("prepacked.pdb") and not overwrite:
            # print("Preparing is done!\n")
            return
        # print("Prepacking the structure ...")
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            '{1}/source/bin/FlexPepDocking.linuxgccrelease -database {1}/database -s {2} -flexpep_prepack -ex1 -ex2 -unboundrot {3} -score:weights weights.wts'.format(
                self.CPU, self.ROSETTA_DIR, "input.pdb", self.INPUT_UNBOUND), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        _, err = proc.communicate()
        if err:
            sys.exit(err.decode())
        os.rename("input_0001.pdb", "prepacked.pdb")
        # print("Preparing of {} done in {:.2f} minutes!".format(seq, (time.time() - tm) / 60))
        return

    def dock(self, seq, overwrite=False):
        # tm = time.time()
        if os.path.isfile("docking_results.silent") and not overwrite:
            # print("Docking is done!\n")
            return
        # print("Docking the prepared structure (prepacked.pdb) ...")
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            '{1}/source/bin/FlexPepDocking.linuxgccrelease -database {1}/database -s {2} -ex1 -ex2 -out:file:silent {3}.silent -out:file:silent_struct_type binary -pep_refine -nstruct 100 -unboundrot {4} -score:weights weights.wts'.format(
                self.CPU, self.ROSETTA_DIR, "prepacked.pdb", "docking_results", self.INPUT_UNBOUND),
            shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        _, err = proc.communicate()
        if err:
            sys.exit(err.decode())
        # print("Docking of {} done in {:.2f} minutes!".format(seq, (time.time() - tm) / 60))
        return

    # def random_ligand_generation(self):
    #     tm = time.time()
    #     if not os.path.isfile("input_L.pdb"):
    #         proc = subprocess.Popen(
    #             'python /dlab/home/gerdos/pywork/STRUCTURE/chain_splitter.py input.pdb L',
    #             shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #         proc.communicate()
    #     if not os.path.isfile("ligand.silent"):
    #         proc = subprocess.Popen(
    #             '{}/source/bin/FlexPepDocking.linuxgccrelease -s input_L.pdb -pep_fold_only -torsionsMCM -nstruct 100 --out:file:silent ligand.silent'.format(self.ROSETTA_DIR),
    #             shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #         proc.communicate()
    #     print("Random ligand generation with FlexPepDock is done in {:.2f} minutes!".format((time.time() - tm) / 60))

    def ligand_prep_fm(self, seq):
        tm = time.time()
        # Check if every minimization is done
        trg = False
        for num in range(100):
            if not os.path.isfile("{}/{}/RANDOM_LIGANDS/{}.silent".format(self.WORK_DIR, seq, str(num) + "a_8_minimized")):
                trg = True
        if not trg:
            return

        # Generating the random peptides
        if not os.path.isdir("/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{0}".format(seq)):
            shutil.copytree("/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/sample", "/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{0}".format(seq))
            info_text = """Number_of_Amino_Acids                8
    Sequence_File                        /dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{0}/Input/sequence.txt
    Contact_Restriction                  no
    Contacts_File                        /dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{0}/Input/contacts.txt

    Number_of_Conformers                 100
    Output_Directory                     /dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{0}
    J_Calculation                        no
    PRE_Calculation                      no
    RDC_Calculation                      yes

    Phi/Psi_Database                     /dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/database/database_options/phi_psi.txt

    Print_PDB                            yes

    J_Coupling                           - - -

    Number_of_Cysteines                  -
    Cysteine_Positions                   -
    Dynamic                              -
    Proton                               -
    Proton_Frequency                     - -
    Intensity                            -
    Intrinsic_Linewidth_Proton           -

    Global_Tensor                        yes
    N_HN                                 yes
    CA_HA                                yes
    CA_CO                                yes
    N_CO                                 yes
    HN_CO                                yes""".format(seq)

            sequence_text = ""
            for num, j in enumerate(list(seq)):
                sequence_text += "{}     {}  0     0.00     0.00  0.00    0.00\n".format(num + 1, j)
            with open("/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{}/Input/info.txt".format(seq), "w") as file_name:
                file_name.write(info_text)
            with open("/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{}/Input/sequence.txt".format(seq), "w") as file_name:
                file_name.write(sequence_text)
            proc = subprocess.Popen(
                '/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/applications/flexible_meccano ~/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{}/ /usr/bin/gnuplot'.format(seq), shell=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            res, err = proc.communicate()
            if err:
                sys.exit(err.decode())
            # PDB files generated by FM have a mistake, correcting it
            for num in range(100):
                with open("/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{}/Output/PDB/{}a_8.pdb".format(seq, num), "r") as file_name:
                    pseu_str = file_name.readlines()
                for j, line in enumerate(pseu_str):
                    if line.startswith("ATOM"):
                        if int(line.split()[1]) >= 54:
                            line = list(line)
                            line.insert(11, " ")
                    pseu_str[j] = "".join(line)
                with open("/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{}/Output/PDB/{}a_8.pdb".format(seq, num), "w") as file_name:
                    file_name.write("".join(pseu_str))
        if not os.path.isdir('{}/{}/RANDOM_LIGANDS'.format(self.WORK_DIR, seq)):
            shutil.copytree("/dlab/home/gerdos/bin/flexiblemeccano/simulations/{0}/Output/PDB".format(seq), "{}/{}/RANDOM_LIGANDS".format(self.WORK_DIR, seq))
        # Simulation
        for num in range(100):
            if not os.path.isfile("{}/{}/RANDOM_LIGANDS/{}.silent".format(self.WORK_DIR, seq, str(num) + "a_8_minimized")):
                proc = subprocess.Popen(
                    '{}/source/bin/relax.linuxgccrelease -nstruct 1 -out:file:silent {}/{}/RANDOM_LIGANDS/{}.silent -out:file:silent_struct_type binary -s {}/{}/RANDOM_LIGANDS/{} -score:weights weights.wts'.format(
                        self.ROSETTA_DIR, self.WORK_DIR, seq, str(num) + "a_8_minimized", self.WORK_DIR, seq, str(num) + "a_8.pdb"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                out, err = proc.communicate()
                if err:
                    sys.exit(err.decode())
        # print("Random ligand generation with FlexibleMeccano is done in {:.2f} minutes!".format((time.time() - tm) / 60))
        return

    def complex_minimization(self):
        # extract the docked PDBs
        if not os.path.isdir('COMPLEX_STRUCTURES'):
            os.mkdir('COMPLEX_STRUCTURES')
        os.chdir('COMPLEX_STRUCTURES')
        shutil.copy('../weights.wts', '.')
        # Check id PDBs have been extracted before
        tgl = False
        for num in range(100):
            if not os.path.isfile('prepacked_{:04d}.pdb'.format(num + 1)):
                tgl = True
        if tgl:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(
                '{}/source/bin/extract_pdbs.linuxgccrelease -in:file:silent ../docking_results.silent'.format(
                    self.ROSETTA_DIR), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            proc.communicate()
        # Minimizing the complexes
        for num in range(100):
            if not os.path.isfile("{}.silent".format('prepacked_{:04d}_minimized'.format(num + 1))):
                proc = subprocess.Popen(
                    '{}/source/bin/relax.linuxgccrelease -nstruct 1 -out:file:silent {}.silent -out:file:silent_struct_type binary -s {} -score:weights weights.wts'.format(
                        self.ROSETTA_DIR, 'prepacked_{:04d}_minimized'.format(num + 1), 'prepacked_{:04d}.pdb'.format(num + 1)), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                out, err = proc.communicate()
                if err:
                    sys.exit(err.decode())

    def read_energies(self, motif):
        # tm = time.time()
        os.chdir("{}/{}".format(self.WORK_DIR, motif))
        complx_ener = pd.DataFrame()
        for num in range(100):
            complx_ener = complx_ener.append(energy('COMPLEX_STRUCTURES/prepacked_{:04d}_minimized.silent'.format(num + 1))[self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES])
        lig_ener = pd.DataFrame()
        for num in range(100):
            lig_ener = lig_ener.append(energy('RANDOM_LIGANDS/{}.silent'.format(str(num) + "a_8_minimized"))[self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES])
        # print("Read energies for {} in {:.2f} minutes!".format(motif, (time.time() - tm) / 60))
        return motif, complx_ener, lig_ener

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid(x):
        # return x
        # return math.log(x, math.e)
        return -math.tanh(0.15 * (math.log(x, math.e) - math.log(1e-4, math.e)))

    def minimizing_func(self, weights_lst, prt=False):
        # if not prt:
        #     print(weights_lst)
        res = 0
        # Energy DataFarmes should not me modified globally
        domain_ener = self.DOMAIN_ENERGY.copy()

        # Domain partial function calculation, independent of peptide
        domain_partial_function = np.float128()
        for num, j in enumerate(self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES):
            domain_ener.loc[:, j] *= weights_lst[num]
        for num, j in domain_ener.iterrows():
            domain_partial_function += math.e ** -np.sum([j[ener_type] for ener_type in self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES])
        # Ligand and complex partial functions are depending on the peptide
        for inner_key, kd_experimental in self.PEPTIDE_KD.items():
            # Copy the pd object, as it is immutable
            complex_ener = self.COMPLEX_ENERGY[inner_key].copy(deep=True)
            ligand_ener = self.LIGAND_ENERGY[inner_key].copy(deep=True)
            # Weighting the energies
            for num, j in enumerate(self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES):
                complex_ener.loc[:, j] *= weights_lst[num]
                ligand_ener.loc[:, j] *= weights_lst[num]
            # Complex partial function
            complex_partial_function = np.float128()
            for num, j in complex_ener.iterrows():
                complex_partial_function += math.e ** -np.sum([j[ener_type] for ener_type in self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES])
            # Ligand partial function
            ligand_partial_function = np.float128()
            for num, j in ligand_ener.iterrows():
                ligand_partial_function += math.e ** -np.sum([j[ener_type] for ener_type in self.ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES])
            try:
                res += (self.sigmoid(ligand_partial_function * domain_partial_function / complex_partial_function) - self.sigmoid(kd_experimental)) ** 2
            except ValueError:
                return np.NaN
            if prt:
                print('{}\t{:.4e}\t{:.4e}\t{:.4e}'.format(inner_key, ligand_partial_function * domain_partial_function / complex_partial_function, kd_experimental,
                                                          abs(math.log(ligand_partial_function * domain_partial_function / complex_partial_function, 10) - math.log(kd_experimental,
                                                                                                                                                                    10))))

        print('\rDifference: {:.4f}'.format(res),end='')
        return res

    def main_func(self, seq):
        # Creating the directory isf not exists, and go in there
        if not os.path.isdir("{}/{}".format(self.WORK_DIR, seq)):
            os.mkdir("{}/{}".format(self.WORK_DIR, seq))
        os.chdir("{}/{}".format(self.WORK_DIR, seq))
        shutil.copy('{}/weights.wts'.format(self.WORK_DIR), '.')
        self.mutate_ligand(seq)
        self.prepack(seq)
        self.dock(seq)

        # Ligand generation with FlexPepDock
        # random_ligand_generation()

        # Ligand generation with FlexibleMeccano
        self.ligand_prep_fm(seq)
        self.complex_minimization()
        return seq

        # def plotData(var, x, y, color1, u, v, color2):
        #     pearR = np.corrcoef(x, y)[1, 0]
        #     # least squares from:
        #     # http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html
        #     A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
        #     m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, np.array(y))[0]
        #     plt.figure(1)
        #     plt.subplot(211)
        #     # plt.xlim([min(x) * 1.1, max(x) * 0.9])
        #     plt.ylim([-8, -2])
        #     plt.scatter(x, y, label='Regi', color=color1)
        #     plt.legend(loc=2)
        #     plt.xlabel("log10(Kd)")
        #     plt.ylabel(var)
        #     plt.subplot(212)
        #     plt.scatter(u, v, label='Uj', color=color2)
        #     # plt.plot(x, x * m + c, color=color,
        #     #          label="R = %6.2e" % (pearR))
        #     plt.xlabel("log10(Kd)")
        #     plt.ylabel(var)
        #     # plt.xlim([min(x) * 1.1, max(x) * 0.9])
        #     plt.ylim([-8, -2])
        #     plt.legend(loc=2)
        #     plt.show()


INITIAL_WEIGHTS = {
    'fa_atr': 1,
    'fa_rep': 0.55,
    'fa_sol': 0.9375,
    'fa_intra_rep': 0.005,
    'fa_elec': 0.875,
    'pro_close': 0,
    'hbond_sr_bb': 1.17,
    'hbond_lr_bb': 1.17,
    'hbond_bb_sc': 1.17,
    'hbond_sc': 1.1,
    'dslf_fa13': 0,
    'rama': 0.25,
    'omega': 0.625,
    'fa_dun': 0.7,
    'p_aa_pp': 0.4,
    'yhh_planarity': 0,
    'ref': 0
}
new_energies = INITIAL_WEIGHTS
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
print('Found {} cores to use'.format(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1))


START_POINT = 7
if os.path.isfile(('/dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/ITERATION/ROUND_{}/weights.wts'.format(START_POINT - 1))):
    with open('/dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/ITERATION/ROUND_{}/weights.wts'.format(START_POINT - 1)) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            new_energies[line.split()[0]] = float(line.split()[1].strip())

for i in range(START_POINT, 50):

    try:
        os.mkdir('/dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/ITERATION/ROUND_{}'.format(i))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    print('Running the inner cycle with weights:')
    for key, val in sorted(new_energies.items()):
        print('{}\t{}'.format(key, val))
    print('----------------')
    if not os.path.isfile('/dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/ITERATION/ROUND_{}/weights.wts'.format(i)):
        with open('/dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/ITERATION/ROUND_{}/weights.wts'.format(i), 'w') as fn:
            for key, val in new_energies.items():
                fn.write("{} {}".format(key, val))
                fn.write('\n')
    returned_ener = InnerCycle('/dlab/data/analysis/STRUCTURES/LC8/ITERATION/ROUND_{}'.format(i)).get_result()
    for key, val in returned_ener.items():
        new_energies[key] = (1 / (i + 1) * returned_ener[key]) + (new_energies[key] * (1 - (1 / (i + 1))))
    print('----------------')
    print('Cycle {} complete'.format(i))
    print('----------------')
    gc.collect()
```

I know its is very long, and that most people do not have the time to debug my failure. I am a biologist, and i am not really well equipped with programming skills yet.

I don't understand why do i run out of memory. How can i debug such an error?

In short the code runs like this:

1. Do a simulation (with `multiprocessing`)
2. Weight the result of
   the simulation (data gathering is done in parallel
   with `multiprocessing`)
3. Minimise the weights with `scipy`
4. Run the simulation with the give minimised results then continue from
   the 2. step

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of full code in order to make your error reproducible. In addition please provide any error messages (full tracebacks) you get.

Comment: The pseudocode i posted at the end is the best MCVE i can come up with. The script is complicated. I don't get an error, i simply run out of memory and the computer freezes as the swap is eaten.

Comment: @GáborErdős Well you did explicitly write "it throws some weird errors". But anyway, have you checked if the system has some memory limits for arrays, or stack size limit? I'm not an expert on this, but when using large arrays in Fortran in Ubuntu one can set `ulimit -s unlimited` in `bash` to avoid exceeding memory limits.

Comment: Yeah sorry i corrected that phrase. I will look into limits